# Storing complex javascript objects as game feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am designing javascript game with pure javascript. Now I would like to introduce feature that would allow me to save state of game (couple of complex objects) to either database or filesystem, so after some time I can continue from where i stoped with game. I would like to know what is easiest solution for this? I assume that such feature is not possible with vanilla js, but maybe needs to be used on nodejs? Is mongodb solution for this (does it allow complex objects -> onesthat contain other objects and so).

Comment: nodejs + mongodb make it easy for you. Yes mongo can store JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

Save your game state using [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the objects and save them in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)..
It would be limited to an individual browser, but you wouldn't need to bother with DB's or filesystem access.

```
// Write
localStorage.setItem('gameState', JSON.stringify(yourStateObject));
// Read
let savedStateObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gameState'));
```